# MBProgressHUD And NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, request, nsurlconnection

I have the following question..
I made an API class with all my functions and they return the result when the url request is finished.

I want to make an loader before the request is made and remove it after it's done.

My request code is this:

```
-(NSDictionary *)makeApiCall:(NSString *)function params:(NSDictionary *)params view:(UIView *)displayView{

__block NSDictionary *json = nil;

[self makeRequestTo:function parameters:params successCallback:^(id jsonResponse) {
    json = jsonResponse;
} errorCallback:^(NSError *error, NSString *errorMsg) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorMsg);
}];


return json;

}


- (void) makeRequestTo:(NSString *) function
        parameters:(NSDictionary *) params
   successCallback:(void (^)(id jsonResponse)) successCallback
     errorCallback:(void (^)(NSError * error, NSString *errorMsg)) errorCallback {

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setLoadingEnabled:true]
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseUrl];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFFormURLParameterEncoding;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",kApiBaseUrl,function] parameters:params];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

//NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        errorCallback(error, nil);
    } else {
        id JSON = AFJSONDecode(data, &error);
        successCallback(JSON);
    }
}];

}
```

But.. this won't work.
The loader only appear after the request is complete and it is removed within a second.

Funny thing, if i call it out from this Api class, it works..
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates to the user interface are only done when the program control returns to the main
runloop. But the synchronous call

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

blocks the main thread and does not return before the request has been completed. Therefore no UI updates are done, in particular your loader is not displayed.

You could use `sendAsynchronousRequest` instead and handle the response (and hide the loader) in the completion block, so the code would roughly look like this:

```
- (void) makeRequestTo:(NSString *) function
            parameters:(NSDictionary *) params
       successCallback:(void (^)(id jsonResponse)) successCallback
         errorCallback:(void (^)(NSError * error, NSString *errorMsg)) errorCallback {

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate showLoader];

    // ... create request ...

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [appDelegate hideLoader];

        // ... handle response ...

    }];
}
```

**But there is another problem with your `makeApiCall:` method:** Since `makeRequestTo:` works *asynchronously*, it returns almost immediately . The completion
block with `json = jsonResponse;` is called *later*, when the request has been completed.
Therefore the `json` variable will always been `nil`.

And there is no way around that. You cannot wrap an asynchronous call into a synchronous
method without blocking the thread. In particular, `makeApiCall:` *cannot* return the
response dictionary.
You will have to change your program logic to work
asynchronously.

Comment: The result was the same..
Any more tips? :/

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: Perhaps you can add the new code to your question, otherwise it is difficult to guess where the problem might be.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: Your new code does not contain `showLoader` and `hideLoader` anymore, so how can the result be the same?? Has that been replaced by `[appDelegate setLoadingEnabled:true]`? In that case, where is `[appDelegate setLoadingEnabled:false]`? - But your code has another fundamental problem, see updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, so how can i wrap this?
I need to show the loader and do the request. After the request was done, remove the loader and return the json.
How can i do it?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: That is not possible without blocking the main thread and therefore blocking all user interface updates. - As I said, you should change your program logic to work asynchronously. For example, if you want to display the JSON response in a table view, you would assign the fetched data to the table view data source in the completion block of `makeRequestTo:...` and then call `reloadData`.

Comment: I dont use tables, so i did it with Notifications.
But now i have another problem.. After the request is done and sent the notification, the app still frozen for 5 seconds.. How can i fix that?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: I have no idea without more information and seeing the relevant code.

Comment: I updated my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938795/nsurlconnection-5-seconds-delay

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: I'm glad that my other answer helped! Is this question now also solved?

Comment: Yes it is! I can't vote up because i dont have 15 rep :(
Now i understand the queue logic thanks to you Martin!