# NSURLConnection 5 seconds delay

Tags: objective-c, request, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

i have the following code to make requests to my api:

```
-(void)makeApiCall:(NSString *)function params:(NSDictionary *)params notificationName:(NSString *)notificationName
{    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseUrl];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFFormURLParameterEncoding;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",kApiBaseUrl,function] parameters:params];


NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"complete");
//..My code        
}];    
}
```

My problem is that, after the NSLog(@"complete"), the app is frozen for 5 seconds..
How can i fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what code follows the `NSLog(@"complete")`? When the "complete" gets visible on the debugger console then the request is finally done. So there can hardly be anything wrong with the code that you posted. The code following the nslog is more likely causing the freeze.

Comment: Hehe, I'd say it is dependent on what "//..My code" does ^^

Comment: You can try to hit the pause button in the xcode debugger while the app seems stuck and see if it shows you what it is actually doing

Comment: Hi guys! The problem wasn't the //My code..
The problem was queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue].
But thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue` parameter of `sendAsynchronousRequest` is the queue on which the
*completion handler block* is dispatched. If you do any UI updates in the completion
handler then you probably should call the method with

```
queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
```